# Prove that for $f\in C^2([-a,a],\Bbb R)$ and even exists some $g(x^2)=f(x)$ with $g\in C^1([0,a^2])$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification, proof-writing

**UPDATE:** I updated the proof below, can you check it please? Thank you in advance.

> Let $a>0$ and $f\in C^2([-a,a],\Bbb R)$ be even. Show that there is some $g\in C^1([0,a^2],\Bbb R)$ such that $f(x)=g(x^2)$ for all $x\in[-a,a]$. In particular $f'(0)=0$.

An even function is defined when $f(x)=f(-x)$ for some symmetric domain. Now, for $x\ge 0$ for any $f$ we can define a function $g(x)=f(\sqrt x)$, what is equivalent to write $g(x^2)=f(x)$. If $f$ is differentiable for $x\ge 0$ then $g$ is differentiable, because $f'(\sqrt x)$ exists and

$$g'(x)=\lim_{y\to x}\frac{g(x)-g(y)}{x-y}=\lim_{y\to x}\frac{f(\sqrt x)-f(\sqrt y)}{x-y}=\\=\lim_{y\to x}\frac{f(\sqrt x)-f(\sqrt y)}{\sqrt x-\sqrt y}\cdot\frac1{\sqrt x +\sqrt y}=\frac1{2\sqrt x} f'(\sqrt x)$$

Because $f$ is even we can define $f(-x)=g(x^2)$ for $x<0$. The unique dubious thing here to conclude that such $g$, as is stated in the exercise, exists, it is to check what happen for $g'(0)$.

First observe that for any even differentiable function $f'(0)=0$ because we can write

$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(-h)}{2h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{0}{2h}=0$$

Then

$$g'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(\sqrt x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(\sqrt x)-f(0)}{\sqrt x\sqrt x}=0\cdot\infty$$

Then, using L'Hôpital and after some algebra, we get

$$g'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f'(\sqrt x)}{\sqrt x}-g'(0)\implies g'(0)=\frac12 f''(0)$$

Because $f\in C^2([-a,a],\Bbb R)$ then $f''(0)$ exists. We must show now that $g'$ is continuous at zero, i.e. that

$$\lim_{x\to 0}g'(x)=g'(0)\implies \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac1{2\sqrt x} f'(\sqrt x)=\frac12 f''(0)$$

So we conclude that $g'$ is continuous at zero and $g\in C^1([0,a^2],\Bbb R)$ as desired.$\Box$

Comment: Note that you want to show that $g\in C^{1}([0,a^{2}],\mathbb{R})$, so you also need to show that $g'$ is continuous up to 0. I would check your computation of $g'(x)$, also. Try using the chain rule on $g(x)=f(\sqrt{x})$.

Comment: In your calculation of $g'(0)$, the second difference quotient is not $f'(0)$. Separately, if $f(x) = x^{2}$, then $g(x) = x$, whose derivative at $0$ is not $0$.

Comment: @RideTheWavelet but $f'$ is continuous, I dont see a reason to think that $g'$ cannot be continuous in any point.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Oh, I see... what a mistake. I will fix it.